# Weird spacing after string in lstlisting

Tags: spacing, listings

Why is spacing before and after vertical bar inconsistent in this listing?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    morestring=[b]',
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}
\lstinline{'foo' | 'bar'}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm using pdflatex, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `keepspaces`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}
\lstinline{'foo' | 'bar'}

\lstset{
    morestring=[b]',
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}
\lstinline{'foo' | 'bar'}

\lstset{
    morestring=[b]',
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keepspaces,
}
\lstinline{'foo' | 'bar'}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why this is happening, and why only after delimiters? The documentation is a bit vague about what is happening if `keepspaces=false`.

Comment: @siracusa I guess it's a byproduct of how `listings` looks for strings, so it swallows spaces as it goes.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what the documentation means when it comes to this option... *"keepspaces=true tells the package not to drop spaces to fix column alignment and always converts tabulators to spaces."*

Comment: @effeffe My approach to `listings` is “try some of the enchantments, one of them will work”.